# Order results by another table?

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a custom forum system and I'm trying to figure out how to put a thread on the top of the list if a user posts in it.

I've got this for my query

```
SELECT 
user_threads.threadID, 
user_threads.title, 
user_threads.uid, 
user_threads.postDate,
thread_messages.posted
FROM 
    user_threads,
    thread_messages
WHERE
    parent = :parent
GROUP BY
    user_threads.title
ORDER BY 
    thread_messages.posted
DESC
```

Which doesn't appear to be working. if I post in a new thread, it remains where it is on the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the tables by the `threadID`. Also, if you just want one row per thread, you need to use the date of the last post.

```
SELECT 
user_threads.threadID, 
user_threads.title, 
user_threads.uid, 
user_threads.postDate,
MAX(thread_messages.posted) AS last_post
FROM 
    user_threads
LEFT JOIN
    thread_messages ON thread_messages.threadID = user_threads.threadID
WHERE
    parent = :parent
GROUP BY
    user_threads.threadID
ORDER BY 
    last_post DESC
```

I used `LEFT JOIN` so that threads will be shown even if they don't have anything in `thread_messages`. If this is not needed, you can use a regular `JOIN` (aka `INNER JOIN`).

Comment: Why not `GROUP BY user_threads.threadID`? Text-`GROUP BY` is less performant and multiple threads may have the same title.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the JOIN condition. Currently you are getting the cross product of `user_threads` and `thread_messages`. That means you got rows for each thread and post in the result.

Try adding something link this

```
FROM 
    user_threads
JOIN
    thread_messages USING(threadID)
```

to get each thread only once in your result set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tie the tables together. You can do this by adding something like `user_threads.threadID = thread_messages.threadID` (second column name is guessed and needs to be checked) to the `WHERE` or by rewriting the query like this:

```
SELECT
    user_threads.threadID,
    user_threads.title,
    user_threads.uid,
    user_threads.postDate,
    thread_messages.posted
FROM
    user_threads
JOIN
    thread_messages ON thread_messages.threadID = user_threads.threadID
WHERE
    parent = :parent
GROUP BY
    user_threads.title
ORDER BY
    thread_messages.posted
DESC
```

And also not, that you probably should replace

```
GROUP BY
    user_threads.title
```

by something like

```
GROUP BY
    user_threads.threadID
```

or

```
GROUP BY
    user_threads.threadID, user_threads.title
```

as sooner or later your thread-titles may be reused while the ID should be "forever" unique. Also threadID will most probably lead to a faster query as the database only needs to compare numbers versus text of various lengths.

Comment: That did it... Gotta wait a minute before I can accept it but that did it. Thank you, sir, you are a gentleman and a scholar.

Answer (score 0):

Use aliases for the tables 'user_threads' and 'thread_messages' i.e.

```
 SELECT 
A.threadID, 
A.title, 
A.uid, 
A.postDate,
B.posted
FROM 
    user_threads A,
    thread_messages B
WHERE
    parent = :parent
   //also do it with 'parent' field if parent is a field of user_threads 
   //A.parent else thread_messages B.parent
GROUP BY
    A.title
ORDER BY 
    B.posted
DESC
```

Comment: I don't think, that this changes anything.